# SQL how to aggregate by date and multiple criteria

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table:

| id | amount | method | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 10 | A | 2022-01-24 12:27:14.440 |
| 02 | 80 | A | 2022-01-24 12:27:14.440 |
| 01 | 20 | D | 2022-02-24 12:27:14.440 |
| 01 | 10 | D | 2022-02-24 12:27:14.440 |
| 02 | 20 | D | 2022-02-24 12:27:14.440 |
| 03 | 30 | D | 2022-02-24 12:27:14.440 |

and I want this:

| method | amount_sum_jan | n_transaction_jan | n_customer_jan | amount_sum_feb | n_transaction_feb | n_customer_feb |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 10 | 2 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| D | 0 | 0 | 0 | 80 | 4 | 3 |

This is a table with 7 column and rows equal to the number of methods.

- AMOUNT: sum of amount in one month of one method
- N_TRANSACTIONS: number of transaction in one month with one method
- N_CUSTOMER: number of customers (id) who used that method in one month

Can I get it with just one query?

Comment: You are showing two result tables, one with 4 columns, one with 3 columns. Is this on pirpose? Or are you looking for one result table with seven columns actually? Then, please describe how you calculate the values in your results.

Comment: What DBMS are you using. Please tag your request with that DBMS. SQL requests should always be tagged with the DBMS in order to get answers that work for that DBMS.

Comment: Dear Thorsen: I have tried to run some queries, but I cannot get this result without manipulating the data afterwards

Comment: Better to handle the presentation from rows to columns in an application language and just fetch the data simply with: `SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM \`date\`) as ym, SUM(ammount) as AMMOUNT, COUNT(*) as N_TRANSACTIONS, COUNT(DISTINCT id) AS N_CUSTOMER FROM tbl GROUP BY ym`

Answer (score 1):

You want to aggregate your data by method and have separate columns for January data and February data. You get this with conditional aggregation (`CASE` expression inside the aggregate function),

```
select
  method,
  sum(case when month(date) = 1 then amount else 0 end) as amount_sum_jan,
  count(case when month(date) = 1 then 1 end) as n_transaction_jan,
  count(distinct case when month(date) = 1 then id end) as n_customer_jan,
  sum(case when month(date) = 2 then amount else 0 end) as amount_sum_feb,
  count(case when month(date) = 2 then 1 end) as n_transaction_feb,
  count(distinct case when month(date) = 2 then id end) as n_customer_feb
from mytable
group by method
order by method;
```

Answer (score 1):

It is called pivot, and would for fix dates look like this.
An aggregation of the method for the year and month, and you can COUNT or SUM your number

```
select 
  `method`,
  SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT( YEAR_MONTH FROM `date` ) = '202201' then `amount` ELSE 0 END) amount_sum_jan,
  SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT( YEAR_MONTH FROM `date` ) = '202201' then 1 ELSE 0 END) n_transaction_jan,
  COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN EXTRACT( YEAR_MONTH FROM `date` ) = '202201' then `d` ELSE 0 END)    n_customer_jan,
  SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT( YEAR_MONTH FROM `date` ) = '202202' then `amount` ELSe 0 END) amount_sum_feb,
  SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT( YEAR_MONTH FROM `date` ) = '202202' then 1 ELSe 0 END) n_transaction_feb,
  COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN EXTRACT( YEAR_MONTH FROM `date` ) = '202202' then `d` ELSe 0 END)    n_customer_feb
from tab1
GROUP BY `method`
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/31d8ef/10

much more interesting would be to make that dynamic